# What is the prior of the Lp Space?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, lp-spaces, maximum-likelihood

Pretty much the title. Not much to add here

I am aware that L1-norm is equivalent to Laplacian prior and L2-norm is equivalent to Gaussian prior. The latter was in my stats textbook and it even had a nice proof as well. The former took me some digging to find out.

However I could not find any good info about it about L3-norm, let alone the entire Lp Space. So my question is. Is there a general prior distribution for the Lp-norm. If so what is the formula of it and, if possible, how is it derived?

Comment: you should start with a prior distribution, and from there get your log likelihood, not the other way around... and from this, you can see that there is no interest in mapping back regularizers to priors, if not for L1 and L2 which are widely used (you can check L-inf here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438429/what-prior-would-lead-to-ell-infty-regularization-of-model-weights)

Comment: I don't understand the question. An $L^p$-space is just a normed space, it doesn't come equipped with any distinguished choice of prior or anything like that.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan. If you take the Maximum Likelihood having a Laplacian as a prior, you end up with L1 loss. Do the same for Gaussian and you end up with L2 loss. I wonder if there are such functions for the rest of Lp. If so which are they?