# Why is it bad to translate from Lp norm to priors?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

It [seems like](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476471) we should start with a probability distribution and infer a log likelihood based on that. Why is it a bad idea to start with regularizers and map this onto priors? For example, if I were walking around an ideal city grid, would distances not follow a Laplacian distribution given the natural L1 distances?

It seems like priors for more generalized Lp norms vaguely follow $e^{-|x|^p}$ ([usually with some normalizing constants](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19910009002)). This doesn't seem well written about in literature. Is this not used often?